# Firefox brower doesn't close when triggering Cypress tests via command line

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress, browser-automation

Currently I have constructed three simple cypress tests which access a given page on domain x.

When I trigger the test suite via the terminal window using the following command:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser firefox
```

The first window opens and the first test gets executed within Firefox browser however the remaining tests are unable to execute due to the following exception:

```
Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\qauni\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:182:22)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
```

Looking further into the problem is seems recordings may be causing the issue (As cypress creates mp4 files based on test executions):

```
Warning: We failed to record the video.

       This error will not alter the exit code.

            Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

**Note:** The first successful test executes but the **browser window remains open**, any ideas?

Firefox version: 75.0,
cypress version: 4.5.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly fine for me. It would be great if you can share your simple code snippet, cypress.json config and any other stuff that you are doing.... I will take a look at it and let you know if there is any issue...

Comment: Thanks @Srinu Kodi it seems firefox cant close the browser for the first test instance, even when modifying the tests to simple open google.com, currently I'm using a windows machine, are you also using a windows device?

Comment: Nope; I am using Macbook.